# Apply third party patch to Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, patch

I am trying to apply [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/patches/547/) patch to Notepad++, but I am not sure how to do that. I have downloaded the .patch file but I don't know how I can apply the patch to Notepad++.

Does anyone know how to apply a third party patch to Notepadd++?

Comment: Do you know how to use Subversion?

Comment: No, never heard of it.

Comment: Well, it's the version control system that Notepad++ uses. You'll need to use it to checkout a copy of the source, use `svn patch` to apply the patch to the relevant source file(s), then build the patched source. You won't be able to apply the patch directly to an existing installation.

Answer (score 0):

Just open it in Noptepad++, then you will see who's who.

The line starting with '-' is to be removed.
The line starting with "+" is to be added.
Other lines are the original context lines.

If the patch is not to long, you can modify the source file manually.